# The editor says that my post "appears to contain code" when there is no code?

Tags: support, bug

I cannot post an answer because the editor says that my post appears to contain code, but there is no code on it.

Here is the answer that was rejected by the editor:

```
**g++ 4.8** simply does not support **C++14**, also *MinGW* is quite outdated when there are more new versions of gcc.

# Alternatives you can use
If you want really to use *C++11* or *C++14* on windows with **gcc** you should be using [`MSYS2`][msys2], [`MinGW-w64`][mingw] (it supports 32-bits too) or [`TDM-GCC`][tdm].

[msys2]: https://msys2.github.io/
[mingw]: http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php
[tdm]: http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/
```

There is any way to override this error?

**Edit:**

I another approach to see if i can bypass the editor but it was rejected too:

```
**g++ 4.8** simply does not support **C++14**, also *MinGW* is quite outdated when there are more new versions of gcc.

**g++ 4.8** simply does not support **C++14**, also *MinGW* is quite outdated when there are more new versions of gcc.

# Alternatives you can use
If you want really to use *C++11 or C++14* on windows with gcc you should be using one of the following options:

- [`MSYS2`][msys2] (Uses *MinGW-w64* internally).
- [`MinGW-w64`][mingw] (it supports 32-bits too).
- [`TDM-GCC`][tdm].

[msys2]: https://msys2.github.io/
[mingw]: http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php
[tdm]: http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/
```

Comment: You could stop indenting by 4 spaces (which identifies a code block), as well as stopping the overuse of the asterisk (* and **) character. There's no "bug" or "feature request" here - this is a simple case of overuse of spaces and punctuation.

Comment: Try using way, way, WAAAAAY less bold and italic. Actually, just less formatting in general. Every name does not need to be marked up as bold or italic or code.

Comment: I tried that, and the results were the same, the error seems to be in the links, if i remove the links i can post the answer but is quite useless because it has no links.

Comment: The backticks around the links mark them as code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed all formatting and the system allowed me to post the same body:

---

g++ 4.8 simply does not support C++14, also *MinGW* is quite outdated when there are more new versions of gcc.

g++ 4.8 simply does not support C++14, also MinGW is quite outdated when there are more new versions of gcc.

#### Alternatives you can use

If you want really to use C++11 or C++14 on windows with gcc you should be using one of the following options:

- MSYS2 (Uses MinGW-w64 internally).
- MinGW-w64 (it supports 32-bits too).
- TDM-GCC.

---

So, just do that. No formatting.

Answer (score 0):

you know when you see that what you are writing has a grey background? That's code! It doesn't matter what you are writing. You are formatting it as a code! How this happens? If you indent your text with 4 leading spaces or if you format your text selecting the {} button on the text editor while writing your answer.

Try removing that formatting and SO will let you upload your answer without any issue or inconvenient